# Como cambiar la fuente de letra en Vuetifyjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify, font-family

Buenas estoy intentando cambiar el tipo de letra en Vuetifyjs pero siempre me muestra la fuente predeterminada de vuetify "Roboto". He descargado la fuente en formato .ttf y la he ubicado en mi proyecto en el src/assets/fonts el archivo de la fuente se llama "gellix-7.ttf" y en el archivo de src/plugins/vutify.js tengo el siguiente código:

```
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
import es from "vuetify/lib/locale/es";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    options: {
      customProperties: true,
    },
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#034638",
        secondary: "#000000",
        accent: "#034638",
        error: "#FF5252",
        info: "#2196F3",
        success: "#4CAF50",
        warning: "#FFC107",
      },
    },
    fonts: {
      body: "Gellix Light, sans-serif",
    },
  },
  lang: {
    locales: { es },
    current: "es",
  },
});
```

Tambien intente cargar la fuente en el archivo principal de App.vue de la siguiente manera:

```
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gellix Light";
  src: url("./assets/fonts/gellix-7.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

html {
  font-family: "Gellix Light", sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
```

Pero tampoco funciona mirando la consola no sale ningun error y siempre se aplica la fuente de Roboto en .v-application.

Comment: de hecho he logrado cambiar la fuente en texto normal pero no en los titulos aplicando el font-faily a .v-application directamente